# How do I set the Name of an Container in Docker.DotNet?

Tags: c#, docker, docker.dotnet

So I have this call, which starts a container:

```
await _client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters()
            {
                Image = environment.DockerImage,

            });
```

How or better said where do I set the name of the conainer

I've tried giving it an extra Parameter, like this:

```
            await _client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(Bootstrap.Get().Agent.ConfigManager.ContainerPrefix,new CreateContainerParameters()
            {
                Image = environment.DockerImage,

            });
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
await _client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters()
            {
                Image = environment.DockerImage,
                Name = "my_container"
            });
```

You can see all the properties in `CreateContainerParameters` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/Models/CreateContainerParameters.Generated.cs).